# Delay between status and response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm doing a ajax request using jQuery, but the behavior is erratic.

Most of the time, this happens (using Chrome);
Ajax POST request is sent
*~400ms wait time*
The request appears in Chrome's network logger with a 200 OK status
The request's response appears in Chrome's response tab
My callback function is called. All is good.

However, completely randomly, this happens;
Ajax POST request is sent
*~400ms wait time*
The request appears in Chrome's network logger with a 200 OK status
*~2000 - 10000ms wait time*
The request's response appears in Chrome's response tab
My callback function is called.
By now, the user has likely left the page because he thought it hung up.

Why is this? What happens during that second wait time?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
This is all happening on the same server
If I visit the requested page manually it takes no more than 400ms to load, without any exceptions.

Comment: Side note: whenever you're sending off an AJAX request, it's a good idea to tell the user that it's happening so that they don't leave the page. Show them a spinner, for a example.

Comment: Even though the HTTP response is 200, this doesn't mean that all the data is transferred to the client. I guess you server haa some hickups while processing the request.